# export nested JSON from GCS into Spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, ndjson

I have a nested NDJSON file that I exported from BQ into Google Cloud Storage. From there I would like to open it in Spreadsheet again as a nested table.

I see a lot of Appscripts to import JSON files but none are for files stored in GCS.

What would be the best solution to open the data table in spreadsheet?

[the csv file I see when I use the tool suggested by Alex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvZ1D.png)

This is the NDJSON example:

```
    {"page":"/xxxx","country":"DE","pageviews":"72136","daily_peak_pageviews":"5465","daily_peak_users":"3118","users_unique":"37763","SEO":true,"campaign_info":[{"channel_group":"Referral","users_c":"16","pageviews_c":"17","title":"404"},{"channel_group":"Social","users_c":"2255","pageviews_c":"3839","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"33185","pageviews_c":"63320","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Referral","users_c":"316","pageviews_c":"556","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"47","pageviews_c":"49","title":"404"},{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"1088","pageviews_c":"1706","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"1888","pageviews_c":"2517","title":"404"},{"channel_group":"Social","users_c":"100","pageviews_c":"132","title":"404"}]}
{"page":"/yyy","country":"DE","pageviews":"67576","daily_peak_pageviews":"5390","daily_peak_users":"2843","users_unique":"32772","SEO":true,"campaign_info":[{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"7","pageviews_c":"10","title":"404"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"30951","pageviews_c":"64345","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"782","pageviews_c":"1303","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Referral","users_c":"265","pageviews_c":"467","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Social","users_c":"889","pageviews_c":"1450","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"1","pageviews_c":"1","title":"404"}]}
{"page":"/zzz","country":"DE","pageviews":"7558","daily_peak_pageviews":"619","daily_peak_users":"331","users_unique":"4117","SEO":true,"campaign_info":[{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"7","pageviews_c":"14","title":"404"},{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"38","pageviews_c":"70","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"3987","pageviews_c":"7309","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"1","pageviews_c":"1","title":"404"},{"channel_group":"Referral","users_c":"18","pageviews_c":"26","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Social","users_c":"70","pageviews_c":"138","title":"OK"}]}
{"page":"hdhh","country":"DE","pageviews":"3616","daily_peak_pageviews":"336","daily_peak_users":"206","users_unique":"2131","campaign_info":[{"channel_group":"Social","users_c":"267","pageviews_c":"379","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"776","pageviews_c":"1394","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"1089","pageviews_c":"1814","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Referral","users_c":"17","pageviews_c":"24","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"2","pageviews_c":"5","title":"404"}]}
{"page":"/ethehh","country":"DE","pageviews":"1394","daily_peak_pageviews":"322","daily_peak_users":"294","users_unique":"1232","campaign_info":[{"channel_group":"Paid","users_c":"61","pageviews_c":"67","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"Social","users_c":"271","pageviews_c":"301","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"3","pageviews_c":"5","title":"404"},{"channel_group":"Referral","users_c":"10","pageviews_c":"10","title":"OK"},{"channel_group":"other","users_c":"888","pageviews_c":"1011","title":"OK"}]}
```

and this is the csv example:

```html
page,country,pageviews,daily_peak_pageviews,daily_peak_users,users_unique,SEO,campaign_info/0/channel_group,campaign_info/0/users_c,campaign_info/0/pageviews_c,campaign_info/0/title,campaign_info/1/channel_group,campaign_info/1/users_c,campaign_info/1/pageviews_c,campaign_info/1/title,campaign_info/2/channel_group,campaign_info/2/users_c,campaign_info/2/pageviews_c,campaign_info/2/title,campaign_info/3/channel_group,campaign_info/3/users_c,campaign_info/3/pageviews_c,campaign_info/3/title,campaign_info/4/channel_group,campaign_info/4/users_c,campaign_info/4/pageviews_c,campaign_info/4/title,campaign_info/5/channel_group,campaign_info/5/users_c,campaign_info/5/pageviews_c,campaign_info/5/title,campaign_info/6/channel_group,campaign_info/6/users_c,campaign_info/6/pageviews_c,campaign_info/6/title,campaign_info/7/channel_group,campaign_info/7/users_c,campaign_info/7/pageviews_c,campaign_info/7/title
/xxxx,DE,72136,5465,3118,37763,true,Referral,16,17,404,Social,2255,3839,OK,other,33185,63320,OK,Referral,316,556,OK,Paid,47,49,404,Paid,1088,1706,OK,other,1888,2517,404,Social,100,132,404
/yyy,DE,67576,5390,2843,32772,true,other,7,10,404,other,30951,64345,OK,Paid,782,1303,OK,Referral,265,467,OK,Social,889,1450,OK,Paid,1,1,404,,,,,,,,
/zzz,DE,7558,619,331,4117,true,other,7,14,404,Paid,38,70,OK,other,3987,7309,OK,Paid,1,1,404,Referral,18,26,OK,Social,70,138,OK,,,,,,,,
hdhh,DE,3616,336,206,2131,,Social,267,379,OK,Paid,776,1394,OK,other,1089,1814,OK,Referral,17,24,OK,other,2,5,404,,,,,,,,,,,,
/ethehh,DE,1394,322,294,1232,,Paid,61,67,OK,Social,271,301,OK,other,3,5,404,Referral,10,10,OK,other,888,1011,OK,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will entirely answer the question since it actually bypasses GCS entirely, but here's a tutorial on how to export BigQuery tables to Sheets https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-crunch-your-business-data-from-sheets-in-bigquery

Comment: Thanks Liksa, but this is not what I am looking for. This explains how to query data from a sheet in BQ but I want to export data from BQ to a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found some scripts to load json files into a Google SpreadSheet, but all of them need to be loaded using a url, so the steps to get a public link to your JSON file in GCS are:

1. Go to your Google Cloud Storage bucket and then in your json file click in the three dots at the right.
2. click into "edit permissions"
3. Click into "Add item"
4. in "ENTITY" choose "User", then en "NAME" type "allUsers" and in "ACCESS" choose "Reader".

Now you have an external link to load your JSON using some scripts, like [this one](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a) or [this other one](https://touren.github.io/2017/08/29/Import_JSON_Data_Returned_From_YouTube_Analytics_API.html), but you need to edit the JSON file or the code a bit.

Another solution (and the easiest one), is to convert the JSON file into CSV using [this tool](http://konklone.io/json/) and then, import the CSV into Google SpreadSheet clicking into "File" -> "import" -> "Upload" and then select your CSV file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. The tool you suggested in your last paragraph doesn't work for me unfortunately, either it is because of the newline-delimited JSON format BQ provides or something else but the output csv does not show me the nested schema and looks different than the original table(the repeated fields are simply written into columns but not in rows below each other)

Comment: @Mira Can you share with me a small sample of your exported JSON and your CSV?

Comment: sure, I added the samples above

Comment: I understand now the problem that you are facing. The JSON and the CSV looks correct, but, as I understand, you want the rows to be repeated as many times as entries you have in the campaign_info array. To do that, you can use a script to transform those parameters into new lines. I have no time to develop the script, I'm truly sorry.

Comment: You could use [Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) to configure your CSV for proper importing into sheets.